# Ubuntu 6.06: Mounting /root/sda1 /root failed: No such device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

An old machine in our office, running Ubuntu 6.06 all of a sudden will not boot up. I get the following info during boot:

```
Uncompressing Linux... Ok Booting the kernel
mount: Mounting /root/sda1 /root failed: No such device
mount: Mounting /root/dev on /dev/.static/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: Mounting /sys /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: Mounting /pro /root/pro failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init


Busybox v1.01 (debian 1:1.01-4ubuntu3) Built-in shell (ash)

Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
#
```

I haven't changed anything on the system as far as I'm aware, and I ran some HD diagnostics and everything seems fine.

After Googling around, I found this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=246895 Which seems very similar to my problem, however when I try to mount the drive with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t ext3 -o rw /dev/hda1 /mnt
```

I get the following error:

> mount:  wrong fs type, bad option, bad
>   superblock on /dev/sda1, missing code
>   page or helper program, or other error
>   In some cases useful info is found in
>   syslog - try dmesg | tail or so

I ran fdisk -l and it says the partition type is Linux.

The output after running dmesg | tail :

```
[12207.483801] init_special_inode: bogus i_mode (101)
[12207.483809] EXT2-fs: corrupt root inode, run e2fsck
[12260.427078] init_special_inode: bogus i_mode (101)
[12260.427086] EXT2-fs: corrupt root inode, run e2fsck
[13716.998799] e100: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex
[13716.998923] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[13727.061967] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[13896.700449] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[13896.700458] init_special_inode: bogus i_mode (101)
[13896.700465] EXT3-fs: corrupt root inode, run e2fsck
```

After running e2fsck -p /dev/sda1, I get the following info:

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 142449 / 9584640 files, 5402711 / 19161520 blocks
```

Now I'm really not sure where to go with this :x

Thank you for looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, e2fsck will not run unless it thinks it should.  You can force it in a situation like this.  Try adding the `-f` flag, like `e2fsck -fp /dev/sda1`.

Comment: But never, ever do it on a mounted filesystem.  Ever.

Comment: Thanks a lot, doing this instructed me to manually run fsck. I did that, and cleared the errors and now the drive will mount. :) I tried to restart the machine and I get Error 15 from GRUB. I'll play around with this and see if I can restore GRUB.